# Matching Tags in CFG: Is it possible to define a suchlike production?

Tags: context-free-grammar

What regularly constitutes a grave incentive for a real CFG parser over a regex parser are matching nested parentheses. Those are easy to specify in a CFG.

But I wonder: what about matching tags ? In order, *exemplum gratia*, to parse BBCode.

Are matching tags (BBCode, XML, HTML) possible in context-free-grammar?

Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the number of possible tags is finite, there is no way to express that in a context-free grammar. It is a specific case of the rule that context-free grammars cannot recognise languages in which a substring must be repeated for the sentence to be valid; this also precludes, for example, writing a context-free grammar which expresses the common constraint that identifiers must be declared before use. (In this case, the substring is the name of the tag; in the programming language case, it would be the name of the identifier.)

If the number of possible tags is finite, you simply need to write one parenthesis-like rule for each possible tag.

Alternatively, if all tags *must* be closed explicitly (as in XHTML, but not HTML), then the grammar doesn't need to distinguish between different tags; it is sufficient to check that the name of the close tag matches the name of the tag it is closing.

A mix of the above two strategies can be used for languages (such as HTML5) where there are a finite number of tags with specific syntaxes, while all other tags require an explicit close tag.

I wouldn't recommend trying to write a CF grammar for HTML5, though, unless you want to spend a good chunk of your life reading and reinterpreting specifications oriented around a [stack-based state machine](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tree-construction). Indeed, I wouldn't recommend trying to write a parser for HTML5, since there are freely-available ones written by people who understand the complexities of the "specification", which is really a moving target.

On the other hand, there are aspects of HTML5 which could have been dealt with much more naturally using a CFG, in which the state machine is neither easy to understand nor particularly easy to implement. (Here I'm *not* referring to the [adoption agency algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#adoptionAgency), which is well outside of the scope of context-free grammars.) For example the end-tag and start-tag omission rules for `<table>` contents could be a lot more straightforward if written in EBNF. (I haven't verified if these are actually correct, and since I left out comment-handling, some tags which I never use, [foster-parenting](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foster-parent) and other mandatory tree manipulations for error recovery, it shouldn't be used other than as a vague outline):

```
Table    ::= (Caption | Colgroup | Thead | Tfoot | TBody)* 
Caption  ::= CaptionOpenTag Content* CaptionCloseTag
Colgroup ::= ColgroupOpenTag? Col* ColgroupCloseTag?
Thead    ::= TheadOpenTag Tr* TheadCloseTag?
Tfoot    ::= TfootOpenTag Tr* TfootCloseTag?
Tbody    ::= TbodyOpenTag? Tr* TbodyCloseTag?
Tr       ::= TrOpenTag (Td|Th)* TrCloseTag?
Td       ::= TdOpenTag Content* TdCloseTag?
Th       ::= ThOpenTag Content* ThCloseTag?
```

Here, `Content` does not include any of the tags specifically mentioned in the above grammar, and it has its own quirky rules for tag omission. It *does* include `UnknownOpenTag`, `UnknownCloseTag` and `UnknownEmptyTag`, with a semantic check for correct name nesting. The grammar is ambiguous; it needs to be augmented with the comment that all shift-reduce conflicts are resolved in favour of shifting. To avoid `Comment` (and some other tags) triggering spurious reduction of optional open tags, `Comment` needs to be included explicitly in many places, unless you simply drop comments in the lexical scan. (I would do that, but the standard forbids it.)

Comment: Hello rici,

I admire your knowledge.

Would you like to tell what is the solution then? Context-sensitive-grammars? Isn't there some clever kind of workaround?

Best wishes

Comment: Yes, @vonspotz, context-sensitive mechanism will definitely do the job. But of course, parsing is not really feasible in this case. So you might want to look at "mildly context-sensitve" mechanisms. These are required to accept copy-like phenomena (cross-serial dependencies) and still be parsable in polynomial time:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildly_context-sensitive_grammar_formalism

Comment: @vonspotz: It's been a while since I looked at HTML5 parsing, but I added a few notes about possible simple workarounds, although as I said in the edit, you're best off leaving HTML5 parsing to the experts; you could build an interesting parser of a subset of the language with non-standard or non-existent error recovery, but it would only be interesting as a learning exercise and frankly I'm not sure what you would be learning :)